# google drive ruby api login with oauth2, what is "authorization code"

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, google-drive-api

I try to use login_with_oauth2 with google_drive, but I can't understand what is **authorization code** in #google_drive.rb doc

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
    "522807807986-gjotv2np4tdqp4do8sq0gds0p2bqugtf.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    'fmWlfzejvx_UtS3CKq2Sl-WQ',
    :site => "https://accounts.google.com",
    :token_url => "/o/oauth2/token",
    :authorize_url => "/o/oauth2/auth"
)

auth_url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(
    :redirect_uri => "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost"
)

# Redirect the user to auth_url and get authorization code from redirect URL.

authorization_code = ''
auth_token = client.auth_code.get_token(
    authorization_code, :redirect_uri => "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost")
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(auth_token.token, 'http://localhost:8087')
```

Answer (score 0):

`OAuth2` is the two-steps authorization mechanism. AFAIU, you have your code simply copy-pasted from [official documentation](http://gimite.net/doc/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive.html#method-c-login_with_oauth), but unfortunately that’s not a working code. It’s just an example. Take a look at the comment marked **red** there: it’s very important:

```
# Redirect the user to auth_url and get authorization code from redirect URL.
```

You are to specify the correct pingback URI for Google server to send the response with your `authorization_code` (now there states `localhost`, which is problematically for Google to understand your IP to send you feedback.)

The summing up: you provide Google with credentials, it replies with JSON, containing your `authorization_code` to the address you specified. After this phase is successfully completed, you may proceed requesting `auth_token`.

Comment: I can manually get the authorization_code through typing in terminal: google-chrome auth_url, how to get it automatically?